# Laravel get date difference

Tags: laravel, date-difference

I have the following

```
"end_time" represents datetime in unix format

$vouchers = DB::table('deals_sales')
                ->whereIn('status', [0, 1])
                ->where('end_time', '>=', strtotime("+5 day"))
                ->get();
```

What I'm trying to achieve is get all results that are going to end between now and next 5 days, but with my query I get even those that are going to expire in 10 days.

I just don't see the logic on how to get it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you want the entries that expire within until a certain date, shouldn't the `end_time` condition be `<=` (less or equal than), instead of `>=` (greater or equal than)?

Comment: if I do that I get all the resuts that are <= (less or equal) than today + 5 days, what I need is: if a deal expires on 20th of July, I want to get all the deals that are going to expire within 5 days before 20th of july, so between 15th and 20th

Comment: something else I tried but I get no results at all is "->where('end_time', '>=', strtotime("+5 day"))""->where('end_time', '<=', strtotime("+6 day"))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using integer timestamps you might be looking for [`whereBetween`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses). Try the follwing:

```php
$vouchers = DB::table('deals_sales')
                ->whereIn('status', [0, 1])
                ->whereBetween('end_time', [time(), strtotime("+5 day")])
                ->get();
```

This will get you the entries that have `end_time` between now and the next 5 days.

Comment: sweet @bogdan multumesc ;)